# nginx rewrite file.php to page.php?page=file

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am really new to nginx and wanted to setup a rewrite but it allways fails for me. What I want is to rewrite `file.php` to `page.php?page=file`, but I only want this to occour if `file.php` dont exist. Can anyone help me with this?

I've tried a few rewrites myself but nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this:

```
location ~ (.*/)([\w\-\.]+)\.php {
    try_files $uri $1page.php?page=$2$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PHP set up right now, but this should work.

```
location /rewrite-test/
{
    root /var/www/my-website/;

    try_files $uri /rewrite-test/page.php?page=$uri;
}
```

You can enable logging to see where it is failing, in case it doesn't work.

```
server
{
    listen 80;

    error_log /var/www/my-website/logs/error.log;

    location /
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then use this command:

```
tail -f /var/www/my-website/logs/error.log
```